# Primefaces dialog hide() function hides also growl

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I use primefaces component dialog on button submit: onstart(PF('').show()) oncomplete(PF('').hide()), hiding dialog also makes growl disappiered, growl shows message from managed bean. Same problem as http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29036
Thanks for any ideas.

```
<p:growl id="growl" life="7000" redisplay="true" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" />

<p:commandLink onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide()" update="users" actionListener="#{userBean.delete(user)}" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" >
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Post **your code** here in an mcve format. But I bet you use autoUpdate="true" on the growl and an ajax hide/close event on the dialog. Then all works as expected. You now have more info to search for a solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

My growl:

```
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" sticky="true" />
```

My button that calls dialog:

```
<p:commandButton global="false"
             icon="#{ico.ico_editar}"
             title="#{act.btn_editar}"
             update=":#{p:component('dAdmObjetivo')}"
             oncomplete="PF('dlgAdmObjetivo').show();"/>
```

My dialogue that is out of form:

```
<p:dialog id="dAdmObjetivo"
      widgetVar="dlgAdmObjetivo"
      modal="true"
      closeOnEscape="true"
      minHeight="300"
      hideEffect="fade"
      showEffect="fade"
      resizable="false"
      showHeader="false"
      appendTo="@(body)">

<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" style="float: right;margin: 10px 0px 10px 0">
        <p:commandButton value="#{act.btn_guardar}"
                         actionListener="#{bean.registrarObjetivo()}"
                         update=":#{p:component('pnlObjetivos')}"
                         icon="#{ico.ico_guardar}" />
        <p:spacer width="5"/>
        <p:commandButton value="#{act.btn_cerrar}"
                         global="false"
                         icon="#{ico.ico_cerrar}"
                         onclick="PF('dlgAdmObjetivo').hide();">
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

My method in the bean:

```
public void registrarObjetivo() {
/**
 * Your code
 */
/**
/**
 * Hide dialog
 */
 RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
 context.execute("PF('dlgAdmObjetivo').hide();");
 /**
 * The growl message
 */
FacesMessage fmsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "El objetivo se registró correctamente", null);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, fmsg);
```

}

Comment: Why? what is the major difference or in other words, what in this code prevents the closing of the growl from happening. Please add some textual explanation to your answer

Comment: you already gave the explanation that notification is hidden, I am adding an example of how he could correct that code

Comment: In my example @Kukeltje (after editing the method) the message is called from the bean after hiding dialogue